# Need to be able to convert from Decimal Degrees (DD) to Degrees Decimal Minutes (DDM) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, gps, coordinates

I have a long list of GPS coordinates in excel in DD format,

```
|Latitude|Longitude|
| -------- | -------------- |
|52.29711|-0.289824|
```

And need to be able to convert them to Degrees Decimal Minutes (DDM) format

```
|Latitude|Longitude|
| -------- | -------------- |
|N 52 17.8266'|W 0 17.3894|
```

I've not been able to find a way to do this. Does anyone know how to do this in Excel?

Latitude          Longitude
N52 17.8266

Comment: are southern latitudes negative ??

Comment: First read:  http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/latlong.aspx